# Where do I ask about the meaning of song titles?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where would the best SE site to ask about the meaning of a song title be?

**My Question**

> What is the meaning of the song title "Mans Not Hot" By Big Shaq?

1. [English Usage and Language](https://english.stackexchange.com) as the question wants to define some words
2. [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com) as it is the title of a rap

These both seem valid to ask the question. Which would be the best one to ask the question on?

Comment: Most of these questions, without an official source, will likely attract opinion-based answers about people's interpretations of a title.

Comment: @gparyani so best not ask it at all then?

Comment: Not necessarily, sometimes artists do release what exactly a song means.

Comment: Assuming it means anything at all. These things are not exactly paragons of literature.

Comment: @gparyani - some sites - such as Literature.SE - accept questions that are more opinion based than other sites.

Comment: Answered already by Big Shaq himself :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQwQqJwWpW4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends.

- If you're after the meaning of some words, rather than title as whole, ask in [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) and focus on the words, not song or title.
- If you're after the meaning of the title as a whole, e.g. its context and how it's related to the song itself, the proper place is most likely [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: what happens if I want both. Do I have to post on both with slightly differently worded questions

Comment: @JakeSymons no, posting same question on more than one site is frowned upon.

Comment: what is the best way of resolving this situation then, if I want the meaning of the words as well as how that relates to the song?

Comment: @JakeSymons sounds like you have two related questions, one for each site.  Customize the question for each site, and maybe cross-link them.

Answer (score 4):

While @ShadowWizard's answer is correct, I'll note that song lyrics - and their titles - are on topic on [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-lyrics) as well. So the literal meaning of the words - ELU or ELL. Analysis - Music Fans or Literature.

Full disclosure: I moderate Literature.SE.